# Force a Transaction to commit from another connection?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

We have a very difficult to track down bug in one of our software solutions that sometimes leaves an open transaction. We have this application in production at a number of sites (read: 70+), and we've only seen this issue twice so far this year at separate locations.

The issue we're having is a transaction that's being left open from the constant connection to the SQL Server. Using `dbcc opentran` shows that there is a single transaction left open. In today's case, it was open from 9:30 AM before we realized it at 1:00 PM. Closing the program with the connection will result in the transaction being closed/cancelled, and all the data from the day thus far lost.

Using `dbcc opentran` it responds with the name of the open transaction was `user_transaction`. Trying to close it with `commit tran user_transaction` gives an error of `The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.`.

I can understand you would almost never want to force the transaction to be committed without the prior connection's knowledge, but is there any way to do so? In this case, we closed the program and we lost a half of day's business worth of data.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll need to track down where the close is being missed. You might consider using the sql agent to email you if a transaction is open longer than a certain amount of time. This way you can start to track down what is causing this and at least ending the program will have a much smaller data loss if you can capture the error after 10 minutes or so.

Comment: Is trivial to [`KILL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx) a transaction in limbo, and that's what you should look into, not force commit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it were possible for a transaction to be committed by another conenction, then it's not a transaction.  If this were possible, it would open the door to way more issues than it would solve.

See this link: http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/3865/forcing-a-transaction-to-commit.html

Comment: I suppose that you're right. I was hoping for a duct tape solution when we should be looking for the real cause. Thanks!